# Converting vehicle instrument cluster lights to LEDs: one light stays on

Tags: circuit-analysis, led, automotive, 12v

I have a 1998 K1500 (GMT-400) and I would like to convert the lighting in the instrument cluster to LEDs. There is a semi-known issue with this type of vehicle, where if an LED light is used for the ABS, the light will always stay on.

Here's what should happen:

1. Key is turned to ignition ON
2. ABS light turns on for 3 seconds
3. ABS light turns off

Here's what actually happens:

1. Key is turned to ignition ON
2. ABS light turns on (full power) for 3 seconds
3. ABS light remains dimly lit until the key is turned OFF

Here are the troubleshooting steps I've tried:

- I isolated the ABS light circut from the rest of the cluster - when I connect the LED directly to the pinouts on the harness the same problem happens.
- If I remove the LED and replace it with an incandescent bulb, the circuit works as normal and the ABS light goes off after 3 seconds.
- When I connect my multimeter to the pinout terminals, it reads 12 V the entire time the key is on, so it doesn't seem like the voltage drops.
- I also tested the amperage with the multimeter, and there is no change in amperage the entire time the key is on.

Here is the troubleshooting I've done to see how many amps the old bulb is using. The multimeter reads 2.9mA, but the light does not come on. It was hard to hold the leads and take a photo at the same time, so I took the photo on the workbench.
[image: troubleshooting circuit]

If I use Ohms Law, 2.9mA at 12v is 4137Ohms.  If I wire the LED with 4150 Ohms of resistance in parallel the LEDturns on as expected and turns off when expected. I'm not sure if I've read the amps correctly, or if this circuit is correct (e.g. does it have too much resistance?). Here's what that circuit looks like:
[image: Working circuit]

What else should I look into to solve this?

Comment: The usual solution is to place a suitable resistor in parallel with the led to simulate the incandescent light bulb load. Being a safety related circuit, the electronics probably measure the load of the light bulb. The led doesn’t provide enough load.

Comment: @Kartman thanks for that - is there a way I can know what size resistor I need?

Comment: Measure the current of the light bulb and use ohm’s law to give you the resistance. Your problem is not new so I’m sure someone has solved it and made a blog post or youtube vid.

Comment: The resistance will change hugely when hot. Measure the on current instead and divide that into 12 V (or whatever voltage it works at) to find the hot resistance.

Comment: @Transistor thank you. I'm still learning, is someplace that can show me how to set up the multimeter for that test?  I'm new enough that I don't even know what to google.  If I add the multimeter in series, it reads 29mA but the incandescent light doesn't turn on.

Comment: @Kartman I would have thought so too, but a few weeks of searching hasn't turned up anything.

Comment: @AK_, that's odd. If it was reading zero I'd have told you the fuse was blown. [Edit] your question and post a nicely cropped photo of the meter setup and connections.

Comment: @Transistor updated my question with images.  I also used that 2.9mA to calculate the resistance, and assuming 2.9mA is correct, using some resistors I'm able to get it working as expected. I'm not sure if I've done both the reading and calculations correctly. Can you help me confirm?

Comment: Current seems too low for an incandescent bulb but let's ignore that for now. Resistance calculation is right. "*If I wire the LED with 4150 Ohms of resistance in parallel ...*" I'm glad you added the photo. You have wired the resistors **in parallel with each other**. You should have wired them **in series with each other** and then wired the series string in parallel with the others. The resistor on the left seems to be 150 ohms and if you add resistors in parallel with that you get < 150 ohms. Revise series and parallel resistor calculations! However, if it works, it works!

Comment: @Transistor thanks thats good information about series and parallel. I used 3k, 1k, and 150 on my breadboard. Since they were all in parallel, what resistance was I actually using?

Comment: @AK_ - you were getting 1 /  ( (1/3000) + (1/1000) + (1/150) ) = 142.85